# Fastlane error: Could not infer your app's version

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I've been using Fastlane for our build in Jenkins system but recently I've encountered a problem which I'm unable to resolve that.

Tested recreating provisioning profile, restarting process, updating fastlane & match & deliver & spaceship.

I'm using Xcode 8.2 and fastlane 2.4.0

[image: Error of fastlane for deliver]

Answer (score 4):

I get the same error "Could not infer your app's version", as a workaround you could specify the version by adding app_version to your DeliverFile.md

> app_version "1.1.0"

or commandline argument to deliver

> fastlane deliver download_metadata --app_version "1.1.0"

[Deliverfile.md docs](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/deliver/Deliverfile.md)

Comment: What's the source of problem?
Problem is here that I can lane without problem form my command line, but this error happens on jenkins build tool!

Comment: I got "Could not infer your app's version" when downloading metadata, so I set the app version, this is not via Jenkins